# Smoothing doesn't work on all edges

Tags: mesh

I am new to Blender, and I try to build cloth model. So far so good, staring from cylinder to the low-poly collar.
[image: low poly of the model]

Still, I am confused after shade-smooth as some edges are smoothed as expected, and some aren't.
[image: after shade-smooth]

I change Mesh's Normals auto-smooth angle to 180d, but still not work ;(
[image]

Any suggestion ?

Comment: I think that "shade smooth" works well only if you have enough geometry (try to add a subdivision modifier)

Comment: Use Autosmooth in Object Mode. Not in Edit mode...

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to merge vertices or to recalculate the normals?

First go to edit mode and select all vertices by pressing A.

To merge vertices, press Mesh -> Clean Up -> Merge by Distance.

This merges Vertices whose distance is below an adjustable treshold. If two Vertices are stacked on each other, smooth shading still works, but it interpolates the normals between these two points and so it looks like a hard edge.

To recalculate the Normals, press Mesh -> Normals -> Recalculate Outside or use the shortcut Shift-N.

This fixes the problem, that two faces might face in opposite directions an so blender is not able to interpolate between them.

Comment: thanks, it works ;)